# How to get out of ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
protected AutoResetEvent _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

protected virtual void ThreadProc()
{
    while (WorkState != WorkStates.Paused)
    {
        while (HasWork())
        {
            if (WorkState == WorkStates.Paused || !DoWork())
                    break;
        }
        _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

So, when thread is started, it checks if there is a job to do, and after it's done, it will wait for _waitHandle to be set. Here is the wake function which is called when a new task is coming in.

```
    public void Wake()
    {
        if ((_thread.ThreadState & ThreadState.Unstarted) == ThreadState.Unstarted)
            _thread.Start();
        else if (_thread.IsAlive)
            _waitHandle.Set();
    }
```

where CreateThread is like this:

```
    protected virtual void CreateThread(bool start = false)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(ThreadProc) { IsBackground = true };
        _thread.Name = GetType().Name;
        if (start)
            _thread.Start();
    }
```

This code works fine most of time, but very occasionally, it doesn't. Normally, when thread is waiting for _waitHandle, the thread is alive and its state is changed to WaitSleepJoin. In this case calling _waitHandle.set() would make it active again. However, sometimes, it doesn't work, although the state is same (i.e. thread is alive and ThreadState is WaitSleepJoin).

It appears it didn't wait at _waitHandle.WaitOne() because calling _waitHandle.set() doesn't trigger. The only way to make the thread looping again is to call CreateThread(true). The problem is how do I know if thread is waiting on _waitHandle or not?

Here is what I have after some research in trying to deal with this problem, but CreateThread() is called way too many times.

```
    public void Wake()
    {
        if ((_thread.ThreadState & ThreadState.Unstarted) == ThreadState.Unstarted)
            _thread.Start();
        else if ((_thread.ThreadState & ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin) == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
        {
            if (!_waitHandle.WaitOne(0))
                _waitHandle.Set();
            else
                CreateThread(true);
        }
        else if (_thread.IsAlive)
            _waitHandle.Set();
    }
```

What I don't understand is, if _thread.IsAlive is true, and its ThreadState is WaitSleepJoin, where is the thread (I made sure there is no active work in thread either)? How to wake it up?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the reason not to use TPL?

Comment: In your Wake method (the last code snippet in your question), why do you create more thread objects and start them and assign them to the _thread field? What's the purpose of this? It looks so wrong...

Comment: It is quite possible that in your original code you created two or more threads running the ThreadProc method. That means, you have also two or more threads waiting on the _waitHandle. Remember that _waitHandle is an AutoResetEvent. If an AutoResetEvent is signalled, only one thread is being woken up and the AutoResetEvent is then automatically resetted (hence its name). Any other threads waiting on this AutoResetEvent will keep waiting. Perhaps when you thought that setting _waitHandle did not wake up your thread, it just woke up another thread and not the one you were looking at...

Comment: On question why not use TPL, that's coming from legacy code and from my legacy mind too, but I'm willing to switch, if somebody can help me translate this code into TPL.

Comment: @elgonzo, as I stated in my question, adding CreateThread in case of WaitSleepJoin state is the only way to get it started again when it's stuck. That's actually the main reason for me to ask this question.

Comment: @elgonzo, I also suspect that waiHandle has been set by another thread, and I'll try to isolate that. However, from my observation, that happened mostly when there is nothing to do for a while, and it appears the thread is in a "deep sleep" mode and can't be waked, although it's still alive.

Comment: What does `DoWork` looks like?